# batch copy multiples .txt with pathname on filename

Tags: rsync, cp, file-copy, clipboard

I am trying to batch copy a lot of .txt files from various directories to Directory "all_txt" I am using fzf to find all text files.

### simple copy

```
cp dir1/file1.txt dir1/file2.txt dir2/file3.txt dir4/dir5/file4.txt /home/user/all_txt
```

After executing the above command in /home/user/all_txt I will get the following

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

### What I need

I need to copy those files along with the pathname e.g

```
dir1_file1.txt 
dir1_file2.txt 
dir2_file3.txt 
dir4_dir5_file4.txt
```

because I have many files with the same name and the simple `cp` command is replacing same files.

### Tried solution

```
cp --parents dir1/file1 dir1/file2 dir2/file3 dir4/dir5/file4 /home/user/all_txt
```

this thing creating the parents directory which i don't want.
I just need all my files in the same directory, containing pathname in the filename.

Thank you!

Comment: So what file names do you want? `dir1/file1` cannot be a file name, that has to be a directory, `dir1` that contains a file called `file1`. Please [edit] your question and show us what format you want your file names to have.

Comment: @terdon as per your suggestions I edit the question.

Comment: @roaima yes the link given by you is what I need. Thanks I appreciate your help